# Bug when cancelling documentation changes

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation

When I make an edit to a document or create a document, save changes for review and later reopen to edit it, make an edit and **cancel changes** (instead of saving them):

[image: Are you sure?]

I get "Your changes have been successfully submitted for review... " whereas actually I have made no new changes after my previous submit (I just discarded whatever changes I intended to make):

[image: Your changes have been submitted...]

This wording should be changed to:

> You have made no changes to the previously submitted document and your previous changes are still under review. Once approved by other users in the community, they will be live.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes, when it does this, it retracts the previous version and submits a new revision, even if you just click the "retract and edit" button, rethink your edit, and click "cancel" without changing anything whatsoever.  Perhaps the issue is deeper than just incorrect wording.

Comment: @JustinTime maybe but I haven't faced that issue till now.

Comment: It seems like it only happens if there's enough of a delay between clicking "retract and edit" and canceling.  If you just cancel a few minutes after, it doesn't happen, in my experience.  If you click the button, start making changes, spend a little time doing research/thinking how best to word things/double- or triple-testing any new code you're adding, decide it was better off the way it was originally, and then cancel (with or without undoing your edits first), it seems to see it as a new edit, not a cancellation.

Comment: [Not sure if this particular bug has been fixed yet, I haven't seen it recently, at least not that I can remember..]

Comment: I played around with some drafts on our development environment and I can't reproduce this notice. It's possible the problem has been fixed. It's also possible I haven't reproduced the conditions needed. Please let me know if this is spotted in the wild again.